# How to use selected value of UIPickerView as time interval for notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications, uipickerview

I'm trying get a value out of the selected row in UIPickerView and, depending on the selected row, set a time interval for repeating notifications. i.e., users choose "Every 2 minutes" in UIPickerView and get a notification every 120.0 seconds.

The second "didSelectRow" method does not seem to store the value in my variable `interval`, I didn't find a solution for that so far.

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import  UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI

class ViewController: UIViewcontroller, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    // The following lines define the parameters for Picker View
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!

    let pickerData = ["Every minute", "Every 2 minutes", "Every 3 minutes", "Every 4 minutes", "Every 5 minutes", "Every 6 minutes", "Every 7 minutes", "Every 8 minutes", "Every 9 minutes", "Every 10 minutes"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myPicker.delegate = self
        myPicker.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        myLabel.text = pickerData[row]
    }

    var interval: TimeInterval = 60.0 // Assume that row 0 is selected by default

    // The following method might be the tricky part I guess.

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
interval = Double(row+1) * 60.0
    }


    let requestIdentifier = "SampleRequest" //identifier is to cancel the notification request

    @IBAction  func triggerNotification(){
        print("notification will be triggered in five seconds..Hold on tight")
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Placeholder"
        content.subtitle = "Placeholder"
        content.body = "Placeholder"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval:self.interval, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
            if (error != nil){
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "User instance is nil")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopNotification(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Removed all pending notifications")
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [requestIdentifier])
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You will need to create an array of values that correspond to your times and then use the selected index of the picker view to get the value from the array

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow you on this. Array of values meaning an array containing 60.0, 120.0 and so on? And how would I use the selected index of pickerview to get a value from the other array?

Comment: Exactly. Then simply `timeDelay = times[row]`

Comment: Ok I think I'm lacking some basic knowledge here. Would you do this inside the `pickerView` method (the one where I'm currently having `let selected = pickerData[row]`)? Also, how would I get the value for `times[row]` from `pickerData[row]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I've solved it by doing the following. Since I noticed that everything is running correctly until the point where I'm trying to store my needed value in `interval` - the method just wouldn't do it, but the method before would assign `row` correctly.

Instead of this

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,          inComponent component: Int) {
    myLabel.text = pickerData[row]
}

var interval: TimeInterval = 60.0 // Assume that row 0 is selected by default

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
interval = Double(row+1) * 60.0
}
```

I included the line `interval = Double(row+1) * 60.0` into the function which has `myLabel.text = pickerData[row]`, like this:

```
var interval: TimeInterval = 60.0 // Assume that row 0 is selected by default
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,          inComponent component: Int) {
    myLabel.text = pickerData[row]
    interval = Double(row+1) * 60.0
}
```

This works and stores the correct value in `interval`, e.g. when you select the row "Every 2 minutes", it stores 120.0.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of minutes and declare your interval variable right under minutes array like so

```
let pickerData = ["Every minute", "Every 2 minutes", "Every 3 minutes", "Every 4 minutes", "Every 5 minutes", "Every 6 minutes", "Every 7 minutes", "Every 8 minutes", "Every 9 minutes", "Every 10 minutes"]
let minutes[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var interval: Inte = 0
```

Change your pickerView didSelectRow function to this

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    interval = minutes[row]
}
```

now you have your interval as int which is from 1 to 10 depending on which row has been selected.

```
@IBAction  func triggerNotification(){
    print("notification will be triggered in five seconds..Hold on tight")
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Placeholder"
    content.subtitle = "Placeholder"
    content.body = "Placeholder"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let minute = TimeInterval(interval * 60)

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval:(minute), repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "User instance is nil")
        }
    }
}
```

I created a new minute variable which is a TimeInterval also multiply interval*60. If interval is 2 then it will be 2*60 = 120 and so on.

Comment: Cool, thanks. But I'm getting the following error on line `let minute: TimeInterval = interval * 60`: "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands" Any idea?

Comment: I updated the example please look there again I changed the minutes array also let minute = TimeInterval(interval*60) it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add 1 to the selected row and then multiply by 60.0:

```
var interval: TimeInterval = 60.0 // Assume that row 0 is selected by default

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    interval = Double(row+1) * 60.0
}

@IBAction  func triggerNotification() {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Placeholder"
    content.subtitle = "Placeholder"
    content.body = "Placeholder"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval:interval, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "User instance is nil")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, this kind of works. But I'm always getting the notification one minute earlier than I'm supposed to get it from the selection (e.g. I select "Every 2 minutes" and get it every minute). Why is that? Does it have to add 2?
Also I presumed it should've said `Double(row+1)`, right?

Comment: Not sure.  The code should be right.  What value are you getting for `row` and `interval`?

Comment: Cannot check at the moment because I'm at work, but I will check later. But I just noticed that the app sends a notification _every minute_, no matter which row was selected. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't cancelled the previous notifications before scheduling the new one

Comment: Thought so too, but that wasn't the issue. Canceled it and then tried again, still sends it after one minute (and repeats).

Comment: Set a breakpoint where you create the notification and confirm what it is doing.

Comment: Ok so I set the breakpoint after the line `let requestIdentifier = "SampleRequest"`, selected the second row in the simulator and the console returned: " interval = (TimeInterval) 60 ". Means, the method doesn't change the value of `interval`, right?

Comment: Sounds like it. Change it to `self.interval` to be sure you aren't accidentally shadowing the property with a local variable.

Comment: Same output, unfortunately.