# How to use selected value of UIPickerView as the content.sound for notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uipickerview

I've read [How to use selected value of UIPickerView as time interval for notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217476/how-to-use-selected-value-of-uipickerview-as-time-interval-for-notifications/43237373#43237373) over and over, but I don't know how to apply the answer to my situation.

Basically, I have coded a picker view with two options. I don't know how to

1) make each picker view row correspond to a certain alarm sound
2) make the content.sound a variable that can be one of the two alarm sound options.

I have the two sound files in my Assets.xcassets already, I just don't know how to program it into the alarm.

This is the code I have so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var soundPickerView: UIPickerView!

let sounds = ["chirping birds", "flowing water"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return sounds[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return sounds.count
}


func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = " wake up call "
    content.body = "Time to wake up!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "Morning Birds.aiff")
```

There's other code for the notification request etc. but the above is just the relevant code. The last line of code is the one I know needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, 
        UIPickerViewDataSource {
        @IBOutlet weak var soundPickerView: UIPickerView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        let dic = [
             "chirping birds" : "MorningBirdsFile.aiff"
            ,"flowing water" : "FlowingWaterFile.aiff"
        ]

        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
        {
            return 1
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
        {
            return Array(dic)[row].key
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
        {
            return dic.count
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
            let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = " wake up call "
            content.body = "Time to wake up!"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: Array(dic)[row].value)


            print(Array(dic)[row].value)
        }
    }
```

or you can take the value of picker view and store it in some variable and when user confirms you set it to your calendar.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! I tried to implement this and got the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'row' " for the last two lines of code, unfortunately.

Comment: have you delegate your class to `UIPickerViewDelegate` have a look on first line of my code. If I copy and paste this code "as is" it works like a charm

Comment: I created a new project to test this code by itself and made sure my ViewController.swift file contained "class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource" but now I'm getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'date' ".

Comment: Thanks so much! I just don't understand why it won't work for me :(

Comment: date is from your own code !! I just copied and paste to illustrate